# How to reload a particular div using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I have a task bar. While selecting a checkbox I need to filter the contents in the task bar. For that I have to reload a particular div.

I tried the following.

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){ 
  '<%@final_tasks= @final_tasks.find(142)%>'
  $("#task_content").reload();
});
```

Here `task_content` is the div class name. But my code was not working. Please help me..

Comment: "not working" is not very descriptive, is it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to send some sort of GET request to your controller for new information.

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
  $.get('/your_controller/task_content', function(data) {
    $("#task_content").html(data.final_tasks);
  }
});
```

So your controller would have some lookup action. Let's call it `task_content`

```
def task_content
  @final_tasks= @final_tasks.find(142)
  # though I assume you want this to be more dynamic so this is just an example
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: {final_tasks: @final_tasks} }
  end
end
```

Then be sure to add a route for that in your `routes.rb` :

```
 get 'your_controller/task_content'     => 'your_controller#task_content'
```

Comment: I will try this and let u know

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
function get_data(val)
{
   $.post('path_fro_data.php',{'value':val},
           function(data) 
              {
                $("#div_task").html(data);
              }
          );

}
```

in the html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check_1" name="check_1" value="1" onchange="get_data(this.value);"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check_2" name="check_2" value="2" onchange="get_data(this.value);"/>
```

in the server scripting(for examle .php page) fetch the data from database corresponding to the data sent.

Answer (score 0):

Created a plugin called refresh, so where ever you need to refresh the content you can call the function. Please check the below code.

```
$.fn.refresh = function(options) {

    var options = {
        contentURL : 'xxx.html'
    };
    options = $.extend({},options);
    return this.each(function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        setTimeout( function() {
            obj.fadeOut('slow').load(options.contentURL).fadeIn('slow');      
        }, 2000);            
    });

};
$('#task_content').refresh();
```